# Unstable lightgbm results on every new process when I restarted the server

Tags: python, random, lightgbm

This is the python code I used for generating trees from my data.

```py
params = {
    'objective': 'binary',
    'deterministic': True,
    'force_row_wise': True,
    'num_threads': 8,
    'learning_rate': 0.05,
    'max_depth': 3,
    'tree_learner': 'data',
    'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
    'feature_fraction': 0.7,
    'bagging_fraction': 0.8,
    'bagging_freq': 5,
    'verbose': -1,
    'seed': 8,
}
random.seed(8)
np.random.seed(8)

dataset = lgb.Dataset(X, y)
bst = lgb.train(params, dataset, 10, keep_training_booster=True)
trees = bst.dump_model()["tree_info"]
```

I was testing it out on my local macbook M2 machine with a flask server.

- The code does give me stable result when I run the algorithm in a row without restarting the process.
- The instability happens when every time I reboot the server
- I've tested out every possible instruction in https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html
- I've even tried setting the random seed of python / numpy, but it doesn't work
- I've also disabled parallelism by setting num_threads to 1, but it doesn't help